# Is there an incompatibility between siunitx and skmath packages?

Tags: packages, siunitx, incompatibility

Is it just me, or does output not look like it is supposed to??

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{skmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\num{\pi}
\end{document}
```

which gives: [image: I am no pi]

`$\pi$` works entirely fine everywhere else, it's just in the `num` (and the `numlist`, which is where I encountered it at first) where it fails. Erroneously believing the output at first to be a `$\beta$`(before zooming in on the output) I tried out `input-symbols=\beta` and using `\beta` which again gave an entirely different but also wrong character, so there probably is some mismatch somewhere.

It took me a while of trial and error elimination of packages to get to the MWE above, but ultimately the culprit turned out to be the `skmath` package. 
Now the question is: Can I do something so I can continue using both (like a dirty hack), or do I need to let one of them go? Or is there something wrong with my setup and others cannot reproduce the error?

**PS:** Switching the order in which the packages are loaded, didn't change anything.

Comment: The culprit is `isomath`. On the other hand, `\num{\pi}` makes no sense.

Comment: @egreg Which `skmath` loads, I'm guessing? Could that maybe prevented?

Comment: Apparently not. The `skmath` package defines a boolean for deciding whether to load `isomath`, but no way to set it to false. Anyway, what should `\num{\pi}` be for?

Comment: @egreg `\num{\pi}` was just the shortest example, i actually had a `\numlist` with several numbers, including `\pi` which caused the same problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not every font has the correct glyphs in `\mathrm` to work 'out of the box'. Here you probably want

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{skmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{math-rm = \ensuremath}
\begin{document}
\num{\pi}
\end{document}
```